# Saved FPDF pdf not displaying variables?

Tags: php, fpdf

I've made an fpdf invoice sheet, displaying all variables correct in the browser (pdf preview in Chrome).
But when I save the pdf, and view it, all my variables are left out!

I first gather my posted data, and then set up the fpdf code, containing my post variables.
Like this:

```
$var1 = $_POST['input1'];
$var2 = $_POST['input2'];

require('fpdf17/fpdf.php');

class PDF extends FPDF {
...
```

I've tried setting my variables as globals, but it doesn't matter.

Help greatly appreciated!

UPDATE: it seems like it's a Chrome issue... Firefox saves the pdf containing my variables correctly. Any thoughts?

UPDATE 2: It seems only POSTED variables are not saved within the pdf via Chrome. Variables holding data from a database are saved correctly inside the pdf.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the problem is you need to inject the variables you want inside of the PDF object:

```
__constructor($var1, $var2) { $this->var1 = $var1; $this->var2 = $var2; }
```

And then

```
$pdf = new PDF($var1, $var2);
```

And use `$this->var1` and `$this->var2` inside of the class.

Comment: But that's only for use with posted data, right?

(Although it works in Firefox without your code...)



Because when fetching MySQL data, it works properly.

But thanks for your example! Might use it some other time.

Comment: Any variable that was not created inside of the class needs to be injected inside. In your example, since the class handles the MySQL connection, it means you don't need to do it with the MySQL variables.

Comment: But still Firefox handles the posted variables without injecting them inside the class...
But thanks for your insight!